# "Not Acceptable" error was generated by Mod_Security

Tags: mod-security

I am running mp3 songs download website. When I try to download a song I get this error:

> Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

My website is http://www.playlist.pk/ you can see to try by download any song. kindly inform me how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

I had bought my [domain](http://santosh-shah.com) 3 months ago. Even I used to get same error. I tried to search in google and found .htaccess code that helped me. I copied the below text and paste it in the .htaccess file at the root of my domain.

I suggest you to do the same. May it help you.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.  SMF is a big boy, it does not need its hands held.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I saw this solution everywhere but not worked for me. It is giving me issue for wp-login.php file

Comment: @MakarandMane Did you fond any fix I have the same issue with wp-login.php

Comment: @AqibBangash I talked with Hosting provider. They told me to change my IP. and I did same by contacting my ISP.