# Can't download a remote file to the server

Tags: php, attachment

The remote file is an attachment, and i can get the headers but i cant get the file or the content of it.

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //not working, with rb too
    //file_put_contents("natives.html", stream_get_contents(fopen("http://www.dev-c.com/nativedb/reference.html", 'r')));

    //same with rb too
    //file_put_contents("natives.html", fopen("http://www.dev-c.com/nativedb/reference.html", 'r'));

    //same
    //echo file_get_contents("http://www.dev-c.com/nativedb/reference.html");

    //same
    /*$url = 'http://www.dev-c.com/nativedb/reference.html';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    echo $data;*/

    //same
    $url = 'http://www.dev-c.com/nativedb/reference.html';
    $file = basename($url);

    $fp = fopen($file, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

So if i use any of those codes, the output is nothing, and the created file on my webserver is empty.
The file: http://www.dev-c.com/nativedb/reference.html

Comment: What is the issue? Is the file empty?

Comment: @RaviGehlot  it does not work without http://

Comment: Is the file empty?

Comment: @RaviGehlot the local file is always empty

Comment: Can you print the contents of phpinfo() and tell me what your open_basedir value is?

Comment: I tried to grab the contents of the URL you provided. It is coming back blank using CURL or wget. With file_put_contents, it is returning FALSE.

Comment: open_basedir -> no value

Comment: As you can see it is an attachment, if you open the link with a browser you can download that file, but i have to download it to the server :((

Comment: Could you give me what you are getting on running this, 
$error = curl_error($ch);
echo $error;

Comment: You might have to follow up here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768681/this-error-was-generated-by-mod-security

Comment: @AnoopToffy there is no any error, i get the response, but thats just the header only. i want the file.

Comment: @Dreadzone Do you have root access to the server that hosts the reference.html file? It is running NGINX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou for the help, but the problem was with the encoding.
I had to send the header "Accept-Encoding: gzip" and then gzdecode the output.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'http://www.dev-c.com/nativedb/reference.html';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Host: www.dev-c.com",
"Accept-Encoding: gzip"
));

$data = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo gzdecode($data);
?>
```

Comment: gotcha. I was going to ask you to disable gzip on the server. But good catch.

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the headers for the web URL that you provided with your example. This is what I got:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 11:34:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
**Content-Length: 0**
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Description: reference.html
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reference.html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Expires: Thu Jun 22 11:34:58 2017 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Pragma: public
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=f9d4eb515eeabfb461a11d056fdc7b78; path=/
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, private, proxy-revalidate`

As you can see, Content-Length: 0 is zero. That might be one of the reasons why you are getting an empty body.

If you have access to the NGINX server that hosts reference.html, you could try to dump the contents of /var/log/nginx/error.log when you try to download reference.html.

If Content-Length is zero, there is no file size to download. It points out to be an issue with the server setup.

Comment: Why i can download trough browser then? I think there is no problem with nginx.

Comment: If you have access to the server, you could place a small file (like test.txt). Something like a text file with just a small string like 'Hello World'. Can that be downloaded using your PHP script? Sometimes, NGINX will bug out on bigger files.